# Cannot find the CREDENTIAL because it does not exist or you do not have permission- Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

I've a Azure SQL database where I'm trying to create an external data source to load CSV data to database from a blob storage.

I've created a database scoped credential using the following query.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [https://forecaststorage01.blob.core.windows.net] 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS KEY',
 SECRET = 'SAS Token';
```

Then created an external data source,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [demodata]
    WITH (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://forecaststorage01.blob.core.windows.net',
        CREDENTIAL = [https://forecaststorage01.blob.core.windows.net]
    );
```

When I try to run the following query,

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BULK INSERT input.RawData
FROM 'csv-data/egypt_sales_data.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'demodata',
      FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

It says

"Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https://forecaststorage01.blob.core.windows.net' because it does not exist or you do not have permission.'

Then I've granted access to database scoped credential to the user 'dbo' using the following query,

```
GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL::[https://forecaststorage01.blob.core.windows.net] TO [dbo]
```

Then I tried to bulk insert again. But it still shows the error,

"Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https://forecaststorage01.blob.core.windows.net', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
"

Why I cannot access the database scoped credentials?

Answer (score 2):

If you try to run the first statement on Azure SQL you should get an error:

```
'CREATE CREDENTIAL' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

You have to use the `CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL` command. And also the `IDENTITY` value *must* be `SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE` not "key":

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [https://forecaststorage01.blob.core.windows.net] 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
 SECRET = 'SAS Token';
```

That should fix your issue

Comment: Did try that. Still doesn't work. :(.

Comment: I just tried again and works perfectly...are you getting the same error?

Comment: yes i'm still getting the same error. Don't know why :(

Comment: Check if you can find the credentials in the system table: `select * from sys.database_scoped_credentials`

Comment: Checked the table sys.database_scoped_credentitals.  It's available there.

Comment: Is the identity set to "SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE"?

Comment: Yes. Its Shared Access Signature.

Comment: Ever found a solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ran below on the instance and it helped me to resolve issue:

```
use master
GRANT ALTER ANY CREDENTIAL TO 
[Replace_with_login_account_you_use_here]
```