# Unable to Query SQL Serverless Pool View as SQL Login

Tags: serverless, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have created several views over parquet files in an ADLS Gen2 data lake storage account in a Synapse Serverless SQL Pool.

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=shared-access-signature#server-scoped-credential) to grant access to the Views to a SQL Login (the views return data when I am logged in as an Azure AD/Entra ID user).

Steps taken so far:

1. Created database master key
2. Created server-scoped CREDENTIAL with same name as data lake e.g.

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://<storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/datalake/**]
WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'
, SECRET = 'SAS token';
GO
```

3. Granted permissions to SQL Login

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON CREDENTIAL::[https://<storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/datalake/**] TO [sql_login];
```

However, on trying to SELECT data from the view or from the file directly, I run into the dreaded error message:

```
File 'https://<storage account name.dfs.core.windows.net/datalake/curated/DataWarehouse/Dimension/Customer/Customer.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.
```

Followed by:

```
Could not use view or function 'dm_dim.Customer' because of binding errors.
```

I've looked at other StackOverflow questions, including:

[Cannot find the CREDENTIAL because it does not exist or you do not have permission- Azure SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70866397/cannot-find-the-credential-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissi)

and:

[Unable to Query Serverless Pool View in Azure Synapse using SQL Admin Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527315/unable-to-query-serverless-pool-view-in-azure-synapse-using-sql-admin-credential)

I am clearly still missing something. I thought at first it was a networking/firewall issue but I checked the networking settings on the storage account and can see that the Synapse instance has access:

[image: Azure Storage Account Networking Settings]

Is this a supported scenario or must I use Azure AD/Entra ID authentication exclusively?

Answer (score 0):

The Views and SQL Logins need to exist inside a SQL Serverless Database. Setting this up can be a bit of a pain, here are the steps we have used successfully in several workspaces, hopefully this will help. Be sure you are executing these commands inside the SQL Database (rather than master).

To start, you need a Database Scoped Credential:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL %YourCredentialName%
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE' ,
  SECRET = '%YourSASToken'
```

Use the credential to create an External Data Source with access to the Storage location:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE %YourEDSName%
WITH 
  ( 
    LOCATION = 'https://%yourAccount%.blob.core.windows.net/%%yourContainer/' , 
    CREDENTIAL = %YourCredentialName%
  ) ;
```

Use the EDS in your View:

```
CREATE VIEW [%SCHEMA_NAME%].[%VIEW_NAME%]
    AS 
    SELECT *
    FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK '%folderPath%',
        data_source = '%YourEDSName%',
        FORMAT='PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

You will need to grant the login references to the Database Scoped Credential:

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL::[%YourCredentialName%] TO [%YourUserName%];
```

You may need to grant SELECT to the Schema:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schema::[%SCHEMA_NAME%] TO [%YourUserName%]
```

If you have additional Schemas that wish to restrict, you may need to explicitly DENY those:

```
DENY SELECT ON schema::[%SCHEMA_NAME%] TO [%YourUserName%]
```

There is one other we have used, but frankly I don't remember why we needed this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA :: [%SCHEMA_NAME%] TO %USER_OR_GROUP_NAME%;
```

**EDIT:**

To create the user, first create a LOGIN **in Master**:

```
CREATE LOGIN %LOGIN_NAME% WITH PASSWORD = '%PASSWORD%';
```

In the database, create a User that references this LOGIN:

```
CREATE USER [%LOGIN_NAME%]
   FROM LOGIN [%LOGIN_NAME%]

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER %LOGIN_NAME%;
```

Comment: I can't get these steps to work. The CREATE VIEW step fails with: File https:/<storage account>.dfs.core.windows.net/datalake/curated/Dimension/City/City.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process. Also, the GRANT REFERENCES failed because it tells me my SQL login account (called sqladmin) doesn't exist in the database, yet when I try to explicitly add the user, it says user already exists in database as 'dbo'.

Comment: Should the view definition only contain the portion of the file path beyond the EDS definition?

Comment: I edited the post and added the details of creating a SQL user.

Comment: Yes, when you references an EDS, it holds the account and container, so the View references only the subsequent path.